# Is it possible to control which items are loaded into a QML file depending on a parameter?

Tags: qt, qml

Question is on the title. Let me give an example to make it clear,
let's say I have 2 products and each have different features; therefore, I need to put different items and elements on the Main qml file. So far I have tried controlling elements using `Q_PROPERTY` and `visible` feature together to check if the parameter has desired value. However, it causes to a total mess, the anchor connections etc. becomes totally uncontrollable because the design also changes, subtly(not critical changes).

So, in short I am looking for a structure that takes a parameter and loads components accordingly.

I also leave an example of what I have done:

In a class,

```
Q_PROPERTY(int productType READ getproductType  WRITE setproductType  NOTIFY productType Changed);
```

And in a qml, I let user to choose which product they have:

```
    Button {
        id: id_typeSelector
        text: "Type 1"
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top


        onClicked: {
            visible: false
            object.setproductType(0)
            splash.timeout()
        }
    }
```

Lastly, on main.qml i determine which component to be showed:

```
visible: productType === 0
```

Comment: You can user a [Loader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) to dynamically load in QML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is the dynamic loading of a component. One way to do this is through the use of Loaders. The following is an example of how to constraint pipe size input based on the pipe material chosen.

- wood pipes: 3", 5" or 7" diameter
- iron pipe: any diameter
- steel pipes: 3" - 8" diameter

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
Page {
    anchors.fill: parent
    ListModel {
        id: pipes
        ListElement { pipeTypeName: "Wood"; productType: 0 }
        ListElement { pipeTypeName: "Iron"; productType: 1 }
        ListElement { pipeTypeName: "Steel"; productType: 2 }
    }
    Frame {
        ColumnLayout {
            ComboBox {
                id: comboBox
                model: pipes
                textRole: "pipeTypeName"
                property int currentProductType: pipes.get(currentIndex).productType ?? -1
            }
            Loader {
                sourceComponent: comboBox.currentProductType === 0 && woodInputComponent
                       || comboBox.currentProductType === 1 && ironInputComponent
                       || comboBox.currentProductType === 2 && steelInputComponent
                       || null
            }
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: woodInputComponent
        RowLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Text { text: qsTr("Wood Pipe Width: ") }
            ComboBox { model: [3, 5, 7] }
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: ironInputComponent
        RowLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            TextField { placeholderText: qsTr("Iron Pipe Width") }
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: steelInputComponent
        RowLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Text { text: qsTr("Steel Pipe Width") }
            RangeSlider { from: 3; to: 8 }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://qmlonline.kde.org/?code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBARRggrsAxgazgJgHQCMArAFCiSyLJpZ4DCEAdjFBADYDOuhp508SVBkx4AMgEMAnhBQwuBHiQAK4gOYBTOAG8ScPXHGN0AC2gc8AM2Bs2ALjhhxUdc137RwDjACyEACbqbNpu+vrAfvZgwGDqHCGhcB5eAKJs6iAu8FoO0eoAKpIxAHLiGfYARADqEP7lANwOrH4o6DAFMfYADHAAvvGhSTCp6ZnaOTHt6iVlcOUAkqyM9Y3+LW2F6vYEvf3unkNpGcxjURMb05uzAMow6oHLYE1rk-Y4O6F9oQBiUKWaOgl9Aw2CgQIwJNJZMFAYCGCAAEYQABCEAAHtCYZjwvZ0BAEci0btMXoQP5ApFcnFiTDbqiYAAldiXcqnfLnP7lInEx4QGKwSRwYDHdAoKDOZhKJ6tF7jWJ4DQwAAUIrFmTmjACqIAlHgec1pRs4AB+I1wAC0BC5Hyt7gg4gCUAx1NCHBkUHQ6jhkEYmRxeMRKNReBV4pgktWBpicAAvLG4N0AGQJuAAdxqfnVYFkXqYmRtzr0AB9C3BcfjA8HRaHw-r1lHY9G4Nsk4LFpns3jvXmC87i6X-QSgyHMjXnoaG7g4C2vHc2O2YDmfa4e9S+4wUDZ8+8YZ99Lu9IvRgCYdjU+n54flzDGSmITIslu77JLNY2JVwjBjPYWCh1Fu8uodJjLSMD2AAjhweRQIqVTpnASi5HA75+J+FRatu1JwgGaJjKSAR2HAADaADMAA0cBEORADsAC6GEJPu9GXg+WIRK2TAXp2uZXoCN5Pixzr8S+NjIahcA-n+BYAXSXzAIEfgnGw4geqYbAOtJoFwBBUEwQsTDwYhonGOU6GMda5lAlxS4CYCp4zoEnHgNxMBcnxUj3k6xJCVYIkfl+4lQL+-6AVk4kheBkHQeUNyzgZUZGSZ9GYvShgaFcbDhOojrZBYrAgPYxENDAED2AAHEle7xH0PRAA)

In the above example, I used the following way of choosing dynamically loading a component, i.e.

```
Loader {
    sourceComponent: comboBox.currentProductType === 0 && woodInputComponent
                  || comboBox.currentProductType === 1 && ironInputComponent
                  || comboBox.currentProductType === 2 && steelInputComponent
                  || null
}
```

If your components where declared in their own QML, e.g. `WoodInput.qml`, `IronInput.qml` and `SteelInput.qml`, we can consider refactoring the code to something shorter, e.g.

```
Loader {
    source: pipeTypeName + "Input.qml"
}
```

The following is a more extended example that uses `StackView` instead of `Loader` to demonstrate switching between Pages where PipeType and PipeLength may be set. A different PipeLength editor is used subject to the PipeType chosen:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Page {
    anchors.fill: parent

    property int purchaseIndex: -1
    property var purchase: purchaseIndex >= 0 ? purchases.get(purchaseIndex) : null

    ListModel {
        id: purchases
    }

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: gallery
    }

    Component {
        id: gallery
        Page {
            header: Text {
                text: qsTr("Gallery (%1 records)").arg(purchases.count)
            }
            ListView {
                anchors.fill: parent
                model: purchases
                delegate: Frame {
                    width: ListView.view.width
                    RowLayout {
                        width: parent.width
                        Text {
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            text: model.index + " " + pipeType + " " + pipeLength
                        }
                        Button {
                            text: qsTr("Edit")
                            onClicked: {
                                purchaseIndex = model.index;
                                stackView.push(edit);
                            }
                        }
                        Button {
                            text: qsTr("Delete")
                            onClicked: purchases.remove(model.index)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            footer: Button {
                text: qsTr("New")
                onClicked: newPurchase()
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: edit
        Page {
            header: Text {
                text: qsTr("Edit #%1").arg(purchaseIndex)
            }
            ColumnLayout {
                Text {
                    text: qsTr("PipeType: %1").arg(purchase.pipeType)
                }
                Text {
                    text: qsTr("PipeLength: %1").arg(purchase.pipeLength)
                }
                Button {
                    text: qsTr("Change Pipe Type")
                    onClicked: stackView.push(changePipeType)
                }
                Button {
                    text: qsTr("Change Pipe Length")
                    onClicked: {
                        let pipeType = purchases.get(purchaseIndex).pipeType;
                        stackView.push(
                            pipeType === "Wood" && changePipeLengthWood
                            || pipeType === "Iron" && changePipeLengthIron
                            || pipeType === "Steel" && changePipeLengthSteel
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
            footer: Button {
                text: qsTr("Done"); onClicked: stackView.pop()
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: changePipeType
        Page {
            header: Text {
                text: qsTr("Change PipeType #%1").arg(purchaseIndex)
            }
            footer: Button {
                text: qsTr("Done"); onClicked: stackView.pop()
            }
            ComboBox {
                model: ["Wood", "Iron", "Steel"]
                onCurrentTextChanged: {
                    purchases.setProperty(purchaseIndex, "pipeType", currentText)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: changePipeLengthWood
        Page {
            header: Text {
                text: qsTr("Wood Pipe Length #%1").arg(purchaseIndex)
            }
            Frame {
                width: parent.width
                ComboBox {
                    model: [3, 5, 7]
                    onCurrentTextChanged: {
                        try {
                            let pipeLength = parseInt(currentText);
                            purchases.setProperty(purchaseIndex, "pipeLength", pipeLength);
                        } catch (err) {
                            console.error(err.message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            footer: Button {
                text: qsTr("Done"); onClicked: stackView.pop()
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: changePipeLengthIron
        Page {
            header: Text {
                text: qsTr("Steel Pipe Length #%1").arg(purchaseIndex)
            }
            TextField {
                width: parent.width
                text: purchases.get(purchaseIndex).pipeLength
                onTextChanged: {
                    purchases.setProperty(purchaseIndex, "pipeLength", parseInt(text));
                }
            }
            footer: Button {
                text: qsTr("Done"); onClicked: stackView.pop()
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: changePipeLengthSteel
        Page {
            header: Text {
                text: qsTr("Steel Pipe Length #%1").arg(purchaseIndex)
            }
            Slider {
                from: 3
                to: 8
                stepSize: 0.1
                value: purchases.get(purchaseIndex).pipeLength
                onValueChanged: {
                    purchases.setProperty(purchaseIndex, "pipeLength", value);
                }
            }
            footer: Button {
                text: qsTr("Done"); onClicked: stackView.pop()
            }
        }
    }

    function newPurchase() {
        let purchase = {
            pipeType: "Wood",
            pipeLength: 3.0
        };
        purchases.append(purchase);
        purchaseIndex = purchases.count - 1;
        stackView.push(edit);
    }
}
```

You can [Try this version Online!](https://qmlonline.kde.org/?code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBARRggrsAxgazgJgHQCMArAFCiSyLJpZ4DCEAdjFBADYDOuhp508SVBkx4AMgEMAnhBQwuBHiRIAFcQHMApnADeJOPrjjG6ABbQOeAGbA2bAFxww4qBuZKDj1mA2xJcYMyOKFCm4hwaAJKMACYaAB4OALQEegZgXj4wfgBuzkEhJmEaDmDBoeFRsXFwAHwAvHAADHAA-PnlGhaaMAAUpQVFlfEAlHAOjCi27gaiwBwwALIQsWw6qR76wNElZYXhHOtwAL7T+gDKMOJYAGrAGgDuaxsGWw7zV5i3D4ceRqbmVhs9kczlcMB+L0YwBgwHEbAiMA0IAcajhbB8kkOJ0ODHATDBT2e-m2cFRtgxEP0qk0hKJBhMGnEsSgDgAKvF4Lo6XTEXEYA4AI4cVlQHoAIgA4miMXAegBSAhwFzoaDRDjDMXDPDONR9XZFCwqlDMYaUjYnbkzOYwL6PLmWjZ-MxQCzWWwlUFuB0bEDLDTA-odA7ejwrDSoxEOABiUHEIC09pDG3uWxgJgcs3mtrw2Tu9zwKeiabN3oAShB7hJpLJaUmiYW0x6XMwC6mTCW6+y+bW69yqzIYIDbAB1NsOFgoDQd3v6Xn8uC+lZ4AJVOAAajgYs368cwG8rMk3h3W63G7Ae40olcamLM6JFrvGwAQrIYEwe4+PHPBcLRWKAKLRNCmrTjOTB0GwwgaCSiaftygZ7JEMTxHADSLv6y7IXEADcoGfu8Nx5ngpQcCYPTQdCwy4XB954Q6D40S+MBvowH40d+cBCiK4oACL+hoiIgTRzzgZBWDQTsAz7HgLi+tkGg9OhbCYVUprCccdHPAxIbaXSulEpYEAQIiLJwExLFsdyHFcX+AByDxCXWolQSSjAPMo+rhD0an0Wa2nYh4uKQG5gSwR4rxwBR4J0tSCagQyTI+GyHKWTyHI-txAFAfAADECqatqUC6ghgxYT5lr6c8DBsCgICMP2NZhQ6XacppGzWb+4rKBeB7eA4+VajqepSRoxE9YeGjlTpbUtalDodZl3XeFejA3umcADYVxWeaN57LdeaZTd6lXcuZ75NUmC1-nQhSrVoS1aL1GiOXezniSSBGfERJFkaEd0PU9R2+b2Z2sRdIZXeKN1GDSD1wCta0vWBjAQS5Djg726LwHtGhPah7SIV0AnDR0QxxFqONPdRwmfdmP09G13qUxNqF1A0YrDkZ0RbgAZDzcB-ZoD0I2mnPLIzDoAD6S7u+4s2z7MRKwjC8-zgsaMLB0mErTAS5a0uy7j8ts5uFwaP6qsC7dQsXiLJhm-6esbFRTsnXpoFuwYhnGUlZmvudbWQ2KPH4pq2FwG9mASXAtPfRAYDeR7flYqccBBfioVmhF6sAxNZqxXN+gJcyyXdhjRJB9Dd1wLnR55QQBVDSVFRlUn3reyZDig4X7XpZxnXB6HVERyjYlRx9lyEQ8xHx4nx2gbiABGEBPhA1Tl88SkOAA2hzXNigANJuOsq0fYoO2wYoALpteBwTNjALVV5oMFO83nR4OEMDKBkvgk4hZMz7M28IfAW98wQtSBhVNutEPABQMOnEKrU6TZ2thrW2WsxbRHzuoOK3pi6+1mhvXufIMp-iwTXC88MtZwHro3Iq-9SqqRgZaGMcY8F1gbOtJwD9WxFnbL2JeK8149zpFvOA28ADMR8iBHwAOw30-HfKAD8n5oNfupFgfhiGYwEobO2+MeEt16OgcBzBIHU3Uvod+Fgv4-3jpkSQjCW5VCARg1aaZQE4zti7dSRwBbiBgKYWUPgoCjB0XWFUjAODsFGqE6A5EVF4HjBwDguDfHCU9tA3sWSNLtyMp3P2zEA69iDiHNyYcR6o3em8SeX1p6QATlA80yc4Gp0QQScGqCYboP2h47WyscE0mIQQ0yRDA59xsuKC+lCjwGLoYNBh78ybNLad6FqUY7hsGiKIgwXCmxgj4beOsHEbF4G6M4pCqkxp9LWrfRgaiekaMfGcuxv8siXMAZubxWsvHOGMT0OcwwMlJlybkjuvtu4RNnJMge5TnrD0jtHWODTZ6rIMCdfy7SIB4iQZZbp-13FrQvkMjhlpRml2QSc2FmUZlw3mZtJuO0VksO5GcSCzJdn6EsKwZEcBJGBwgA4AAHG1eYGgwBnGAAAL2KE0QgbVcg1TlWci5yyyo3MvFre51w4STmftHaFGxXkCXsd4P+6rXHfKJZ4o+SrJwgumvPfJPtTJQomaQ-umV4WVKRRPD4dM0WsrWRi1OlhjToBhO+Ny9wPIjW8pZLGBMij42IcAuVe9liH1Aj8-pDhJF4EaH5SxxqdoWHEGAbwMRLmOo8JalCDQzlGkCIkOABAS0eBRfmemUVHUnCOEAA)

Comment: Thanks, this is quite similar what I am looking for. But I have a question, 
I let user to choose which product they have in another screen, say splash screen, so I am taking information from another page. But, when I implemented this way, I *think* Main.qml automatically gives values to currentProductType like 0, 34343 ... etc before user even chooses which product he has. So, this causes a problem.

Comment: Hi @screamingeagles, inter-page communications can be handled with satisfactory property scoping (everything from Main.qml will be seen in children pages), property binding, signal/slot mechanisms, callback functions, or Promises. Dependent on your detail, one or more of these approaches may apply.

Comment: Hi again @screamingeagles, I implemented a second example that illustrates StackView and Page transitions above. It works by keeping a ListModel and context in the parent context and accessing them from the child Pages.